# NestJS/Mongoose - Create an Array of Object with reference to another Schema

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm building the back-end side of a personal application, and I have two particular models/schemas. One if for Products an another for Orders. I want to do the following:

The Orders need to have the following array with this structure:

```js
products: [
  {
    product: string;
    quantity: number;
  }
]
```

The product should be an `ObjectId` of mongo, and this needs a reference for a 'Product' model.

How I can reach this?  I don't really know how to "type" this with the `@Prop()` decorator.

```js
@Prop({
    // HOW I DO THIS?
})
products: [{ quantity: number; product: mongoose.Types.ObjectId }];
```

This is my Order Schema:

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type OrderDocument = Order & Document;

@Schema()
export class Order {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ type: Number, min: 0, required: true })
  total: number;

  @Prop({
    type: String,
    default: 'PENDING',
    enum: ['PENDING', 'IN PROGRESS', 'COMPLETED'],
  })
  status: string;

  @Prop({
    // HOW I DO THIS?
  })
  products: [{ quantity: number; product: mongoose.Types.ObjectId }];

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Customer',
    required: true,
  })
  customer: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  })
  owner: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ type: Date, default: Date.now() })
  createdAt: Date;
}

export const OrderSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Order);
```

Comment: Maybe you should use mysql or other relational database, because it will be easier for you to organize relationships between tables if there are many of them

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
@Prop({
    type:[{quantity:{type:Number}, product:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId}}]
  })
  products: { quantity: number; product: Product }[];
```

Comment: but when get data by findByIdAndUpdate query i have not receive products key. but in database its available.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to achieve both reference population and mongoose schema validation is to create a subschema for the nested entity.

```js
import { Document, SchemaTypes, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Schema({ _id: false, versionKey: false })
class OrderProduct {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  quantity: number;

  @Prop({ type: [SchemaTypes.ObjectId], ref: 'Product', required: true })
  product: Product[];
}

const OrderProductSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(OrderProduct);

@Schema()
export class Order {
   // other order schema props ...

  @Prop([{ type: OrderProductSchema }])
  products: OrderProduct[];
}
```

Comment: don't you mean @Prop({ type: [OrderProductSchema] }) ?